# How to create Bulma button element rather than HTML <a>, using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bulma

This is my js script. It only creates an anchor tag with text rather than a bulma button.

```
elementos.forEach(function(value,index){
    var button = document.createElement("a");
    button.class = "button is-primary is-rounded";
    button.innerHTML = "Element " + (index +1)+ ": " + value
    container.appendChild(button);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your syntax.

This is the correct way to [add a class to an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) with Javascript:

```
button.classList.add("button is-primary is-rounded")
```